# How to filter a select multiple by property name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter the options of a select multiple, using a text I type in a input text

```
<label for="countryFilter">Filter</label><br>
<input id="countryFilter" ng-model="countryFilter" type="text">
<label for="countries">Countries</label><br>
<select
  id="countries"
  ng-model="countries"
  ng-options="option.name for option in countryOptions track by option.id | filter:{name: countryFilter}"
  multiple>
</select>
```

I want to filter by country name but this code does not work. I also tried

```
 | filter:countryFilter"
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `track by` after the `filter`

`ng-options="option.name for option in countryOptions | filter: {name: countryFilter} track by option.id"`
or
`ng-options="option.name for option in countryOptions | filter: countryFilter track by option.id"`

```html
<select
  id="countries"
  ng-model="countries"
  ng-options="option.name for option in countryOptions | filter: {name: countryFilter} track by option.id"
  multiple>
</select>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/oNPdrGz)